# Image area mapping is showing Infinity instead of numerical value

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js

I'm using the library `react-image-mapper` to put clickable areas on an image and on the initial load, the html generated shows the area with a value of infinity causing the image to not be clickable. After reloading the page, the mapping is working properly. It seems as though the computation by the library is not fast enough when the page initially loads then gets cached afterwards.

I'm using NextJS to build the app and it should be working, but not sure why it's not working on the initial page load.

I don't mind finding a workaround like doing a quick reload when the page initially loads or presenting the user with a spinner as the computation behind the scenes completes.

Thanks for any help with this!

**Inital Page load:**
[image]

**After Reload:**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone experiencing the same, I wasn't able to fix this exact issue, but found a workaround. In a `useEffect` I put a `setTimeout` function to check the value of the `coords` attribute and if it was `Infinity`, the page reloads.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let mapCoordsInfinity = document
        .getElementsByTagName('map')[0]
        .areas[0]?.attributes[1]?.nodeValue?.toString()
        .includes('Infinity');

      if (mapCoordsInfinity || mapCoordsInfinity === undefined) {
        router.reload();
      }
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
```

The reload happens so fast, you don't even notice it so it should be fine for now until I can think of a better fix down the line. Hope this helps someone in the future!